# Python implementation to generate csv file using json file and timestamp of directory

Tags: python, json, csv

I have scheduler that generates six folders and json file using python.

```
'Folder_1', 'Folder_2' 'Folder_3', 'Folder_4', 'Folder_5', 'Folder_6'

JSON file : {"0": [1, 2, 3], "1": [4, 5, 6]}
```

Now I need to implement python script to generate csv file with (unique_id, timestamp of folder, boolean).

Output csv file should be like this

Example:

```
      (0, Folder_1 timestamp, false)
      (0, Folder_2 timestamp, false)
      (0, Folder_3 timestamp, false)
      (1, Folder_4 timestamp, false)
      (1, Folder_5 timestamp, false)
      (1, Folder_6 timestamp, false)
```

Could anyone please provide me the approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.stat` to get the timesamp. Feel free to use `atime`, `ctime` or `mtime` as described in the [stat doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.ST_ATIME).

```py
import os

folders = 'Folder_1', 'Folder_2' 'Folder_3', 'Folder_4', 'Folder_5', 'Folder_6'
json_file = {"0": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}

with open('folder_stats.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('id,timestamp,other_field\n') # csv header
    for folder, file_id in zip(folders, json_file['0']):
        f.write(f'{file_id},{int(os.stat(folder).st_ctime)},0\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful. Did few changes to the question, Could you please give some inputs..

Comment: Assuming your folders are ordered, you could create a first loop `for group_id, folder_ids in json_file.items()` first, and then a second one `for folder_id in folder_ids` and then using `folders[folder_id - 1]` to fetch the matching folder.